# how change tradingview datafeed loader interval

Tags: charts, tradingview-api

In the implementation of a Trading View Widget chart with our own data feed, the getBars function automatically defines the date range for the chart. However, I would like to set a specific interval to call ajax load history data. How can I modify the interval to achieve this customization?

In the blow image you can see history calls.

[image]

I would like change speed of history calls request.